# Elastic search backup - snapshot disk whilst running?

Tags: elasticsearch, backup

Im running a single ES instance. After I have inserted around 100k documents would I be able to take a snapshot of the disk where the data dir is and restore it without any issues every time? (Whilst ES is still running).

Or do I need to shutdown ES, or have an explicit "write all inserts to disk" config?

MySQL Innodb tables will only restore cleanly if you take the disk snapshot after MySQL has run its shutdown. Is ES the same?

My ES version:

```
   "version": {
      "number": "5.4.2",
      "build_hash": "929b078",
      "build_date": "2017-06-15T02:29:28.122Z",
      "build_snapshot": false,
      "lucene_version": "6.5.1"
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that this will contain a useful point-in-time snapshot that can be restored. You would need to jump through several hoops to ensure this (stoppping indexing, flushing, ensuring no merges are happening). As this is too complicated the official way of doing a backup is using the [snapshot and restore API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-snapshots.html). This ensures a valid point in time snapshot, that can also be restored on other clusters.